# How can I figure out the class name of the service builder for the Android Client Library, generated by the Google App Engine script?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, service, client, classname

Okay, so let me be more specific. I am following this guide:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

BUT, when I reach this point, I hit a roadblock (#Python_Creating_the_service_object):

```
//You must use a service object to make requests to the Endpoints API. For unauthenticated requests, construct the service object as follows:

Tictactoe.Builder builder = new Tictactoe.Builder(
AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
service = builder.build();
```

The thing is, I have constructed the client library and included all the correct .jars, but I cannot find out what Tictactoe is a placeholder for? What name can I use, or rather, where can I find that out?

Best regards

---

ANSWER:

For reasons unbeknownst to me, eclipse refused to recognize the content of my jar file, with the builder in it.

If you have the same problem, here's how you solve it:

1. Extract the content of the .jar file with your source in it (command:jar xf [...-sources.jar] )
2. Copy the file into you workspace

Damn Eclipse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons unbeknownst to me, eclipse refused to recognize the content of my jar file, with the builder in it.

If you have the same problem, here's how you solve it:

Extract the content of the .jar file with your source in it (command:jar xf [...-sources.jar] )
Copy the file into you workspace
Damn Eclipse...